# Statistics: How to Calculate the Popularity of a given Book using it's Rentals history Count?

Tags: statistics

I was not sure whether to post this on StackOverflow or MathOverflow, I thought this is more math-related so I post it here(mathoverflow). My post was rejected and somone redirected me to MathExchange.

I'm running a library and I'm making a website for it, I got stuck on how to calculate the popularity of a book given how many rents it got on the month, I'm not so good at math I tried to use the following equation.

Basically, every time a book gets rented I increase its `Popularity` value by $1$ and at the end of each month I divide all books `Popularity` using a calculated divider defined as

$$ \text{Divider} = \min {(2, \max {(1, \text{Average(Popularity)})} )} .$$

As a constraint, the `Divider` should be between $1$ and $2$.

I'm sure that this way is very bad, and I don't know why but I won't feel relaxed if I use it.

Is there a better way to implement this function?

Comment: Can you explain why you want to divide by 'something'? Why not just report the top 10 or 20 most rented books? (If you feel some books were not rented even more because of limited availability, then you might just mention that.) // The reason this question is getting bounced around is that you haven't given your own concept of popularity of a book, so any answer has to be based on an opinion, not on your absent criteria.

Comment: @BruceET sorry if the question was not clear, basically I divide book's popularity each month so that if I add a new book it would have a chance to be popular too, say for example Book `A` has `1000` points but it didn't increase in the next month let's say after dividing it's points they became `600` points, now Book `B` I added it just this month (new) but it and luckily it exploded this month it got `700` points....

Comment: .... so because I divided Book `A` now Book `B` is on top (with `100` delta points), because Book `A` didn't get rented that much in that month, if I didn't divide Book `A` it would still be on top even though it was not rented much this month. this is called `popularity` , if I just select the top ones without dividing that would be called `rank`... I hope this clarifies it, sorry my English is so bad.

Comment: This is my own implementation, I'm asking for a better one using a statistically correct mathematical equation.

Comment: I rhink you need a clear definition of 'popularity' more than you need a correct mathematical equation.